# Disposable object is already disposed when the inner scope is not yet finished

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

I want to write an IEnumerable extension to execute a `Select` in parallel, but with a maximum number of parallel instances. Furthermore I want this extension to have a return value of `IEnumerable<Task<TOutput>>` and not `Task<IEnumerable<TOutput>>`.

I tried this using a semaphore. To cancel the whole execution I also provided a CancellationTokenSource.

```cs
public static IEnumerable<Task<TOutput>> SelectParallel<TInput, TOutput>(
    this IEnumerable<TInput> inputList,
    Func<TInput, Task<TOutput>> selectFunction,
    int numberOfParallelTasks = 50)
{
    // Cancellation source to cancel all tasks if one task fails.
    using var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    // Limit the number of parallel tasks.
    using var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(numberOfParallelTasks);

    return inputList
        .Select(async input =>
        {
            try
            {
                // Wait until a slot is available, to only execute numberOfParallelTasks tasks in parallel.
                await semaphore.WaitAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token);

                return await selectFunction(input);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Activates the cancellation token for all tasks, when one task fails.
                cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                semaphore.Release();
            }
        })
        // ToList() is required to dispose the semaphore and the cancellation token source,
        // otherwise the select can be executed in an outer scope, when the elements are already disposed.
        .ToList();
}
```

I then wrote a test to make sure this function behaves correctly:

```cs
[TestMethod]
public async Task SelectParallelShouldOnlyCallThreeTimesInParallel()
{
    // Arrange
    var timer = new Stopwatch();
    timer.Start();

    var enumerable = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    async Task<long> TestFunction(int i)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);

        return timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }

    // Act
    var result = (await Task.WhenAll(enumerable
        .SelectParallel(TestFunction, 2)))
        .ToList();

    // Arrange
    var first = result.Take(2).Average();
    var middle = result.Skip(2).Take(2).Average();
    var last = result.Skip(4).Take(2).Average();

    var middleToFirstDiff = middle - first;
    var lastToMiddleDiff = last - middle;

    middleToFirstDiff.Should().BeGreaterThan(100);
    lastToMiddleDiff.Should().BeGreaterThan(100);
}
```

This test will fail - even worse it will end up in an endless loop. The reason is, that the `semaphore` is disposed, before the last `Select` block has executed its finally block. When I temporary remove the using keyword from `semaphore` the test will pass.

Is there something wrong with my code or is this a general issue / misunderstanding of Disposable objects and different execution scopes?

Comment: The code returns Task objects, they don't execute until you `// Act`.  Which does kill the CancellationTokenSource and SemaphoreSlim too early.

Answer (score 1):

Walking through your code, it:

- Creates a `SemaphoreSlim`.
- `Selects` through an input sequence, which will lazily create a sequence of tasks.
- Calls `ToList`, which forces all the `Select` delegates to run. This creates a list of tasks.
- Disposes the `SemaphoreSlim` (implicitly at the end of the block).

The problem is that the semaphore is disposed even though the tasks are still running. However, you *want* the method to return a sequence of tasks that are still running.

To resolve, you can either:

- Just remove the `using`. I *think* (but am not 100% sure) that the `SemaphoreSlim` disposal won't do anything in this case since there's no OS semaphore involved with this usage.
- Manage a reference count for the semaphore and then only dispose it when the reference count reaches zero. Note that this has to be threadsafe; you can use my Nito.Disposables library if you want something else to handle the reference counting for you.

You still have another potential problem with your logic: there's no guarantee that the returned tasks will complete in order, or even *start* the `selectFunction` in order, because a `SemaphoreSlim` does not guarantee FIFO ordering.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The order of the completion does not matter. In fact this can differ, depending what the tasks actually do and, for example, how a potential remote server respond. I think you have answered the root cause of my question: I want the method to return a sequence of running instances, therefore I think it’s not possible to dispose it at this time. Thank you!